# Single column DGV to accept clipboard data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I've set a windowsform up.
Currently it it has a single DataGridView that is linked to a single table in a SQL Server db.
I can browse the current data in the table.

How do I set things up so that a user can copy and paste a single column of data from an Excel sheet into the DGV ?

If, in Excel I have 'x' in A1 and 'y' in A2 then this must preserve the number of rows when pasted into the DGV i.e for this example it would still be over 2 rows

I've tried to adapt the following from [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36850/DataGridView-Copy-and-Paste). If fails on the line if `(oCell.Value.ToString() != sCells[i])` with a `NullReferenceException was unhandled` What am I doing wrong?

```
    private void uxChargeBackDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        PasteClipboard();
       //uxChargeBackDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = Clipboard.GetText();
    }


    private void PasteClipboard()
    {
        try
        {
            string s = Clipboard.GetText();
            string[] lines = s.Split('\n');
            int iFail = 0, iRow = uxChargeBackDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            int iCol = uxChargeBackDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            DataGridViewCell oCell;
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (iRow < uxChargeBackDataGridView.RowCount && line.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] sCells = line.Split('\t');
                    for (int i = 0; i < sCells.GetLength(0); ++i)
                    {
                        if (iCol + i < this.uxChargeBackDataGridView.ColumnCount)
                        {
                            oCell = uxChargeBackDataGridView[iCol + i, iRow];
                            if (!oCell.ReadOnly)
                            {
                                if (oCell.Value.ToString() != sCells[i])
                                {
                                    oCell.Value = Convert.ChangeType(sCells[i],
                                                          oCell.ValueType);
                                    oCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
                                }
                                else
                                    iFail++;
                                //only traps a fail if the data has changed 
                                //and you are pasting into a read only cell
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        { break; }
                    }
                    iRow++;
                }
                else
                { break; }
                if (iFail > 0)
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} updates failed due" +
                                    " to read only column setting", iFail));
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The data you pasted is in the wrong format for the cell");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple and will do the trick:

```
private void gridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{
    gridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = Clipboard.GetText();
}
```

edit*

If you want to paste into multple cells and not a single cell then check out this blog post:

http://happysoftware.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/c-code-snippet-paste-to-datagridview.html

Comment: why have you chosen the CellDoubleClick event Duane ?

Comment: When you double click a cell in the DGV, it gets whatever is in your clipboard.

You don't have to use that exact event, but it will do what you want anyway.

Comment: ok - my fault - I'll edit the question. This works but pastes everything in one cell! So if I have 'x' in A1 and 'y' in A2 then this code pastes 'xy' in the cell I double click. I want the info to still get pasted across the same number of rows as it uses in Excel.

Comment: Thanks Duane; I found something oncode project but having trouble adapting it - maybe you can tell me what I doing wrong Duane?! I'll add it to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Refer these: [how to PASTE (Ctrl+V, Shift+Ins) the data from clipboard to DataGridView (DataGridView1) C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e9cee429-5f36-4073-85b4-d16c1708ee1e/)
and [Copy and paste into a DataGridView cell (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527728/copy-and-paste-into-a-datagridview-cell-c)

```
private void form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //if user clicked Shift+Ins or Ctrl+V (paste from clipboard)
    if ((e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert) || (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V))
    {
       /// your paste copy/paste code here
    }
}
```

There are lots of reference SO Thread and another article on this topic follow these to implement your task..
[DataGridView Copy and Paste](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36850/DataGridView-Copy-and-Paste)
[Copy Paste in Datagridview Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/208281/Copy-Paste-in-Datagridview-Control)
[DataGridView DataBound Copy, Paste, Drag, Drop](http://jrwren.wrenfam.com/blog/2007/09/08/datagridview-databound-copy-paste-drag-drop/)
[Row copy/paste functionality in DataGridview(windows application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089689/row-copy-paste-functionality-in-datagridviewwindows-application)

[Get cell contents of a selected row in a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746319/get-cell-contents-of-a-selected-row-in-a-datagridview)
[How to: Get the Selected Cells, Rows, and Columns in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8x9zk5a.aspx)

Hope this help..